# Chunking parenthesis with NLTK

Tags: python, regex, nltk, chunking

I am working with NLTK and I am trying to chunk `(AIM 20-40-60)` from the following text:

`text = for more information refer to the Business Reporting Policy (AIM 20-40-60)`

Currently I am using the following chunk pattern `grammar = r"CHUNK:{<NN.*><CD>}"` which is able to perfectly capture the `AIM 20-40-60` part.

Nevertheless I also want the parenthesis `()` to be part of the chunk as well and since I am relatively new to regular expressions and chunking, I don't know the exact regEX pattern for capturing the parenthesis.

Comment: Try `grammar = r"\(CHUNK:{<NN.*><CD>}\)"` (or `grammar = r"CHUNK:{\(<NN.*><CD>\)}"`)

Comment: I tried both versions but unfortunately it doesn't work. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: Well, you got the gist. Add `\(` and `\)` somewhere inside those tokens.

Comment: The chunker pattern matches the sequence of POS tags, not the surface string. So instead of the the literal `()`, you need to match whatever tag they are given by the POS tagger.

Comment: @lenz hey man you are right. just solved the issue. this is the pattern I used `grammar = r"CHUNK:{<\(><NNP><CD><\)>}"`

Comment: Could you make that an answer? It would remove this from the list of unanswered questions "[regex] answers:0".

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the folloing

`grammar = r"CHUNK:{<\(><NNP><CD><\)>}"`